# How do you declare a timeout when using waitForVisible or give Test Cases a maximum amount of time to run before failing in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm researching Selenium and see use cases for writing the code by hand and using Selenium IDE. One problem I am having with Selenium IDE is specifying a timeout.

For example, I can have it wait for this element to be visible:

```
<td>waitForVisible</td>
<td>css=img.in-cart-image</td>
<td></td>
```

But what if there is an error and that element never shows up? It will just wait forever. I could use the pause command but then the test will have to wait for the entire pause.

Is there a way to add timeouts to individual commands or entire Test Cases in Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the commands that include wait (clickAndWait, waitForVisible etc), indicate that the script will wait (the maximum time to wait is defined in selenium ide options and the default is 30") until the action to be completed (like the element becomes visible). Finally, you can change inside the test case the default time with the following command:

```
<tr>
    <td>setTimeout</td>
    <td>90000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep.

See which gives trivial example:

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

And selenium Api doc:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html